# What's give me annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity and class GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I try to understand method-level resource permissions. I know that annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` allow to define annotatoin `` 
`@PreAuthorize` or `@PreAuthorize` with Spring Expression Language to have more control over accessing to resource but basiclly I can achive that without `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` e.g.

```java
    @GetMapping("/hasscope")
    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.isOAuth() and #oauth2.hasScope('GITHUB') or 
    #oauth2.hasScope('ROLE')")
    public String helloScope(final Principal principal) {
        return "This method use preauthorize annotation !";
    }
```

I have access to `#oauth2` object without this annotation and I can create custom expression rules, like above.

I omitted something or I don't understand correctly. What's the difference between use that or just ignore ? In what shape it improve the security of the methods?

Comment: No you cannot achieve this without the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. You can place the annotations but they will be ignored. However the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` needs to be present BUT it can be that another configuration class imported/used by you. Or if you use Spring Boot it is enabled by default as well.

Comment: Yes, you right I'm using Spring Boot here but I couldn't find any docs which would describe that. That's why I was confused.

Comment: Spring Boot autoconfigures security when Spring Security is on the classpath, which is explained in the Spring Boot reference guide.